# Delete row from db after certain condition has been meet in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.4

My table has data `id post_id description and dispose_time`. I wanted to delete data from DB if current time and date is greater than the current time.

```
 $post = Post::delete()->where('dispose_time' > DATE_SUB(NOW())), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE));
```

something like this . it is giving me the error and the dispose_time in my DB is in timestamp format something like this `1555107000` .
Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delete clause at last , like this:

```
Post::where("dispose_time", ">", now()->addMinutes(-10)->toDateTimeString())->delete();
```

Comment: it gives this error :-  Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'dispose_time' (SQL: delete from `posts` where 'dispose_time' > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))

Comment: what does now refer too

Comment: now() is a helper function, return carbon object, i edited it again

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now()

Answer (score 1):

Use Carbon for time in laravel.

```
$post = Post::where('dispose_time', '>', Carbon::now())->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, you should use the `whereRaw` method, and not `where`, since you are using SQL as where clause. Also, `delete()` should be the last method to be called. So your code would be the following:

```php
Post::whereRaw("`dispose_time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)")->delete();
```

Since you are using Laravel, it comes with the Carbon package and you can also do the following

```php
Post::whereDate('dispose_time', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(-10))->delete();
```

Comment: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'dispose_time' (SQL: delete from `posts` where 'dispose_time' > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))

Comment: Please try the second approach I just presented.

Comment: i am using lumen and i dont know its defination from which package it is coming

Comment: If it does not comes out of the box with lumen, you can check it out [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Also, are you sure `dispose_time` is configured as timestamp?

Comment: I take date and time in postman and apply strtotime function to it and in DB it is string

Comment: Can you place an example of a value stored on your DB?